# Django FileField Model that doesn't upload but returns path of the file

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to build an app where I ask the user to choose some files from his/her computer and the app will process them and write an output file in the same directory.

If I use the FileField model in Django, it uploads the file to the MEDIA_ROOT directory. That's not what I want. I would like the file to remain where it is and I need the path to the file where it is instead. I have been looking at the FileField code:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/models/fields/files/#FieldFile

Does anyone know of a hack around this where the upload_to is disabled and the storage method that is being used returns the path instead? From what I could make out, the storage method reads the file and writes it into the upload_to directory. The FileField class uses the FieldFile class and the FileDescriptor class. Does anyone know which method actually performs the read and therefore has the actual path of the file? Been trying to read the code but I am not at an advanced stage yet and I can't understand all of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "I would like the file to remain where it is"? Isn't it on the client's machine? Exactly what type of "path" would you expect to see, and how do you plan to use it?

Comment: Thanks. Suppose my Django server is running on my home folder /home/xyz/learning_django/example but the file abc.csv is in /home/xyz/datadir/, the file abc.csv gets copied to /home/xyz/learning_django/example/media_files. I can't seem to get the path to /home/xyz/datadir/. Because my intention is to process this csv file and write an output.txt file back to /home/xyz/datadir/.

Comment: Remember that Django is a web framework, and you are therefore building a web application. The client (browser and file upload widget) aren't guaranteed to be on the same machine as the server (and in fact they are usually different machines). In general, a local, client-side path is useless to a web application. Even when they are the same machine, as they are here, the web application may not be able to access an arbitrary local directory. Instead of fighting this model, I recommend embracing it. Let it do the upload and then process the file from its upload location.

Comment: Thanks again. I see your point. The reason for trying to fight this is I am using Django to build a user interface for an app that I now run from command line. So basically, this app will be run from the local computer always. Right now, there are a few Python files that need to be copied into any folder where the user needs processing. So even if I upload the file to media_files, I would like to write output.txt file to another directory where the user files are. I'll try to rewrite those three functions and see if I can work something out.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around Django as a UI for an existing tool. Of course, I don't know the details of what you've built, but it seems to me that many of the benefits that Django brings (ORM, admin, third-party libraries built around traditional web applications, etc.) wouldn't apply, at least not with as much benefit. What are you trying to gain by writing your UI using Django? Is it mainly the request / response, routing and templating parts?

Comment: I have this app which is a circuit simulator (http://pythonpowerelectronics.com/). To use it, you need to describe electric circuits as spreadsheets (read the Documentation for an example), copy the simulator files into the same folder and run a file called circuit_solver.py. All inputs are through spreadsheets and the simulator asks you questions once in a while. Finally, the output which is plots, the user needs to plot with a software like MatPlotLib or Gnuplot. I want to bring all this into one interface and for that I was thinking of Django.